# Error handling in automated script

Tags: php, cron

I have a script that is run via CRON.

The script includes a selection of database calls which are saved into variables and used in calculations. The calculations are then saved into the database.

As the code runs automatically, I am unsure how to approach errors. For example, if one of the variables couldn't be found, this may throw off another part of the script and make it fail.

```
// Database call

// Assign variables
$variable1 = $row->record_1;
$variable2 = '???';
$variable3 = $row->record_3;

// Database call using variables
// WHERE col_1 = $variable2 

// ERROR
```

As this is an automated process, how best should you handle the errors?

Comment: I guess you could wrap your database calls into error handling functions which can then email you when there is DB error or write them to error logs or something.

Comment: Yep, i would prefer to write log files. Additionally you can send new log entries once per day via email to not flood your mailbox.

Comment: Thank you. Would you recommend that I complete all database calls / assign variables, then test for errors, then complete calculations? or just catch errors as the script runs through?

Comment: Can you define 'errors'?
If you know what values to expect for each variable, you can evaluate these variables before sending them to your database.
If a variable is not set or holds an unexpected value, don't send it to your database (it may still be valid sql syntax) but log it to a logfile and check the logfile afterwards.